# General question about calculating Work (pumping water out of tank)

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm fine with calculating the work done when pumping water out of a tank. Set up the integral:
$\int_{span\ of\ depth}\rho gh \ dV$

Where typically $h$ is the height to the surface of the water outside the tank and $dV=length \ dy$
Where the length can be rewritten as a function of y to follow the outside of your curve (since we're integrating with y).

I just have a conceptual question. This formula is assuming we are pumping water from the bottom of the tank.

Suppose we are to pump this water into another tank, and fill that tank bottom-up, would that make us calculate the work also done going into the second tank? $W_{total} = W_{emptying} + W_{filling}$ ?

Comment: Depends where the other tank is relative to the first tank. If it’s right at the top of the first tank, then only the work required to elevate the water to that height is sufficient and gravity would do the rest.

Comment: I agree, but hypothetically if the water was pumped into the bottom of the tank (say the tank is above the first one some distance), then we would need to add the works for each tank?

Comment: Yes you would, as the increasing volume of water in the upper tank will increase the pressure of water there, resisting further filling. In that case, you have to add the work required to elevate the water to the height of the second tank and and that for filling it up.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)